# Playstation Network 2 Step Verification assigned to old phone

Tags: ps4, psn

I recently changed by Playstation Username and was signed out of my account as a result. Only when attempting to sign back in did I realise that the 2 Step Verification was assigned to an old mobile number. Without the 2-Step Verification code, I cannot sign back in.

[I looked here for help on this issue](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Help-with-2-Step-Verification-issues?language=en_US) but for all of the solutions, I need to be **already signed in** to my account.

Does anybody know a way which I can reset the number on my 2 Step Verification without already been signed in?

E.g. For forgetting passwords an email link is often sent, but I cant find anything similar for this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Contacting Playstation Support might do you more favors than we can here.

Comment: ^^ That.  2 factor authentication is not something you're going to bypass without their help, or let's face it, it wouldn't be doing its job very well!